# Группировка и агрегация числовых и строковых значений в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть `pd.DataFrame`. Вывод `data.head()`:

```
    userID  browser         slot    n_clicks    n_queries   n_nonclk_queries
0   1       Browser #2      exp         23          32      19
1   3       Browser #4      exp         3           4       2
2   5       Browser #4      exp         29          35      16
3   6       Browser #4      control     12          6       0
4   7       Browser #4      exp         54          68      30
```

Значение в `userID` может повторяться. Уникальным считается комбинация `userID` и `browser`. Мне необходимо преобразовать данные таким образом, чтобы `userID` был в табличке уникальным, со значением равным сумме по всем браузерам для конкретного `userID`.

Как это сделать эффективно?

**Дополнение**

После преобразования данных, я планирую разделить данные по группам (`slot`)

```
exp_clicks     = data[data["slot"] == 'exp'].n_clicks
cntrl_clicks   = data[data["slot"] == 'control'].n_clicks
```

И проверить гипотезу о равенстве средних с помощью критерия Манна-Уитни

```
stats.mannwhitneyu(exp_clicks, cntrl_clicks)
```

`Slot` — это обозначение группы (экспериментальная/тестовая), люди (`userId`) из одной группы не встречаются в другой.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример выходного / результирующего DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame (я специально добавил запись для `UserID==1` с `Browser #33`):

```
In [221]: df
Out[221]:
   userID      browser     slot  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries
0       1   Browser #2      exp        23         32                19
1       1  Browser #33      exp       100        100               100
2       3   Browser #4      exp         3          4                 2
3       5   Browser #4      exp        29         35                16
4       6   Browser #4  control        12          6                 0
```

Решение:

```
In [222]: df.groupby('userID', as_index=False).sum()
Out[222]:
   userID  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries
0       1       123        132               119
1       3         3          4                 2
2       5        29         35                16
3       6        12          6                 0
```

---

**UPDATE:** несколько вариантов для агрегирования текстовых данных:

Исходный DF:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   userID      browser     slot  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries
0       1   Browser #2      exp        23         32                19
1       1  Browser #22      exp       100        100               100
2       1  Browser #33  control       200        200               200
3       3   Browser #4      exp         3          4                 2
4       5   Browser #4      exp        29         35                16
5       6   Browser #4  control        12          6                 0
```

группировка по `UserID` и `slot`:

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['userID','slot'], as_index=False).sum()
Out[5]:
   userID     slot  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries
0       1  control       200        200               200
1       1      exp       123        132               119
2       3      exp         3          4                 2
3       5      exp        29         35                16
4       6  control        12          6                 0
```

преобразование значений из столбца `slot` в CSV:

```
In [24]: funcs = {c:'sum' for c in df.select_dtypes(include='number').drop('userID',1).columns}

In [25]: funcs
Out[25]: {'n_clicks': 'sum', 'n_queries': 'sum', 'n_nonclk_queries': 'sum'}

In [26]: funcs['slot'] = lambda x: x.values.tolist()

In [27]: df.groupby('userID', as_index=False).agg(funcs)
Out[27]:
   userID  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries                 slot
0       1       323        332               319  [exp, exp, control]
1       3         3          4                 2                [exp]
2       5        29         35                16                [exp]
3       6        12          6                 0            [control]
```

оставляем первое значение `slot` из группы:

```
In [28]: funcs['slot'] = 'first'

In [29]: funcs
Out[29]:
{'n_clicks': 'sum',
 'n_queries': 'sum',
 'n_nonclk_queries': 'sum',
 'slot': 'first'}

In [30]: df.groupby('userID', as_index=False).agg(funcs)
Out[30]:
   userID  n_clicks  n_queries  n_nonclk_queries     slot
0       1       323        332               319      exp
1       3         3          4                 2      exp
2       5        29         35                16      exp
3       6        12          6                 0  control
```

Comment: Спасибо! Появилась проблема с тем, что в таком случае уходят значение колонки "slot", а с ней мне необходимо работать в будущем. Конечно, я могу заранее по ней разбить данные и для каждой группы применить группировку. Все же возникает вопрос: можно ли сгруппировать так, чтобы не потерять колонку "slot"? (slot — это обозначение группы эксперимента, один человек не встречается в двух группах.)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, именно поэтому я попросил привести пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе ;) Можете ппивести в вопросе выходной dataset, но так чтобы в оригинальном dataset присутствовали дупликаты ? Пока непонятно что вы хотите получить в столбце `slot` в качестве результата если присутствуют дупликаты

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, судя по тому, что вы хотите получить в результате данные с уникальными `UserID`, данные придется группировать по `UserID`. При группировке все столбцы кроме `UserID` (по которому группируем) будут агрегированы (сумма, среднее, первое или последнее значение в группе и т.д.). Какой вид агрегирования должен использоваться для столбца `slot`?

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Когда я вручную преобразовывал данные, я оставлял первое значение (`data[data["userID"] == user_id].slot.values[0]`).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, дополнил ответ несколькими вариантами агрегирования для `slot`...

Comment: Очень здорово, спасибо большое!